# CDK how to add assume role while creating a role from an existing role using from_role_arn

Tags: python-3.x, aws-cdk

I have a step function that has multiple lambdas and connections. Now this step function uses an existing role using the following method:

```
self.state_machine_role = _iam.Role.from_role_arn(
            self,
            "statemachinerole",
            role_arn="existing-role-arn",
            mutable=False,
        )
```

now I want an event to invoke this step function, as per [event-documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-events-targets-readme.html) I need to add `ServicePrincipal('events.amazonaws.com')` to this role. So my question is how I'm going to modify `state_machine_role` to have this new service principal.

This existing role `existing-role-arn` has already `states.amazonaws.com` associated with it along with other policies to run my lambdas and step-function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to define role for event Rule neither the statemachine, CDK creates for you better.

See the ref here: [AWS GuardDuty Combine With Security Hub And Slack](https://dev.to/vumdao/aws-guardduty-combine-with-security-hub-and-slack-17eh)

Answer (score 0):

AWS CDK created roles will be much easier for you to use but if you have to use the existing Role, you can't update the Trust Policy document directly from AWS CDK however you can still implement AwsCustomResource with AwsSdkCall to do that for you.

Comment: ahh...have to use sdkcall, thanks for this heads up

Comment: Most welcome, please let me know if you need more help on that